# What's wrong with my data, received through JQuery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm making an API call with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://example/example.json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("apikey", "user")
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.folder.item);
    }
})
```

That returns nothing, except for an error in the console saying:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined"

The JSON data looks like this when I use the url in the browser:

```
{
    "folder": {
         "item": 123123,
         "item 2": false,
         "item 3": "content",
         "item 4": [
             {
               "subitem": "content"
             },
             {
                "subitem": "content2"
             }
         ]
    }
}
```

I was expecting "123123" in the alertbox, but nope. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Log `data` to the console, and see what it actually contains.

Comment: Also look at the response in the Net tab of your developer tools and make sure you are getting back JSON (with the correct content-type).

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I'm not very experienced with code so it did not come up to me to log it to the console. That made me see the whole authentication is not done correctly. The API does not offer Javascript examples, so the whole call I created is just not working. Thanks for the tip, I'll keep it in mind when I walk into problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

If its a JSON string you are getting it will need to be parsed. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://example/example.json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("apikey", "user")
    },
    success: function(data){
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(parsed.folder.item);
    }
});
```

Or to force jquery to parse it for you:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://example/example.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("apikey", "user")
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.folder.item);
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought jQuery does this automatically?

Comment: @Mathletics — It does **but** only when the server outputs the correct content-type (or you override it with `dataType`).

Comment: if you add `dataType: "json"` to `ajax` parameter

Comment: @Mathletics Oh, to be honest I am not sure on that. I think you need to set the data type on the ajax call to force jquery to do that automatically.

Comment: I don't think that's it... This makes the console say: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o". I looked it up and saw another stackoverflow post saying that indicated that there was no need to parse the JSON string.

Comment: @Joris508 you should log the variable. Whenever I see unexpected token it usually means the json I'm parsing is messed up somehow.

Comment: Yes, I commented on the question itself with something similar: the JSON was messed up. Logging helped figuring out the issue.

Comment: @Joris508 oh cool. So you figured it out? Glad you were able to! Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, I did. The API that I'm using has really bad documentation for using it with Javascript so it was quite a struggle, but it works!